# Why do I keep getting this file error?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read information in from one file, it will then convert the information that was read in and output it to another file. I then need to delete the original file and rename the first second file that contains the updated information. I am trying to do this by calling the original file, converting the information and saving the information into the new file, then use the delete function and the rename function that is in C++. any idea why I am getting an error while opening the file?

data.txt contains

- XCIX
- 4999
- XI
- IX
- 55
- 95

temp.txt is empty

both are saved in C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Roman Numerals\Debug

```
int main() 
{
fstream dataFile;   
fstream outfile;    
string line;
string output;
outfile.open("temp.txt", ios::out);
dataFile.open("data.txt", ios::in);

if (!dataFile)
{   
    cout << "File Error\n";

}
else
{
    cout << "Opened correctly!\n" << endl;
    while (dataFile)
    {
        if (dataFile.eof()) break;
        getline(dataFile, line);
        if (line[1] == '1' || line[1] == '2' || line[1] == '3' || line[1] == '4' || line[1] == '5' || line[1] == '6' || line[1] == '7' || line[1] == '8' || line[1] == '9' || line[1] == '0')
        {
            outfile << numbertonumberal(line) << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            outfile << romantonumberal(line) << "\n";
        }
    }

    dataFile.close();
    remove("data.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "data.txt");
    cout << "All values have been converted are are in the original file\n";
    outfile.close();
}


return 0;
}
```

My output is a single line that says File Error.

Comment: Have you verified that data.txt actually exists, and that the working directory of your project when it starts up is where you think it is?

Comment: Note that working directory is not necessarily the one your executable resides in.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to only close the output file AFTER you've renamed it from temp.txt to data.txt. Ouput may be buffered and only be flushed to the physical file when it's actually closed.

Comment: @antred It will be flushed to the same node though which will by then be called data.txt.

Comment: @wakjah You saved me, I didn't have it saved in the correct folder now I need to get it to actually rename the file.

Comment: @Cthulhu Good point. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

At first: check file. It's exists? And you have some mistakes at code:

```
if (!dataFile) // incorrect. datafile is instance of class but not ponter
if (datafile.is_open()) // correct. use a method from fstream class

while (dataFile) // incorrect. its true while object "datafile" exists (see above)
while (!datafile.eof()) // correct. And you don`t need "if (dataFile.eof()) break;"
```

So, your code should be looks like this:

```
if(datafile.is_open()) {
    while(!datafile.eof()) {
        getline(datafile, line);

        ... // use isdigit() function for compare with digits (<cctype> header)
    }
} else {
    cerr << "Cannot open file" << endl;
}
```

Comment: ostream-like classes have a conversion operator for boolean contexts that, when called, returns true if the stream is in a good state, i.e. in this case if it's been opened and can be read from. The expression "if (!dataFile)" is perfectly acceptable.